# What is this number before SRC folder - Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

What is this number just before SRC folder ? Please let me know any solution to remove this annotation. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bookmark. Use Navigate | Bookmarks | Toggle bookmark to remove it.